# through model for an Abstract model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have an Abstract model:

```
class Distributor(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and 2 models which inherit it:

```
class DistributorGroup(Distributor):
    pass

class DistributorPerson(Distributor):
    pass
```

also I have a llink model:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    distributors_persons = models.ManyToManyField(
        'people.DistributorPerson', blank=True, related_name='distributors_persons_of_links')
    distributors_groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'groups.DistributorGroup', blank=True, related_name='distributors_groups_of_links')
```

A link can have a relation with one of the distributors. I accomplished this behavior by adding 2 m2m and setting `blank=True` to both.

Now I realized that I need a `through` model to connect `Distributor`s and `Link`. But as `through` model can't have an abstract model as a foreign key I don't know what to do. Do I need to create 2 separate `through` models for `DistributorPerson` and `DistributorGroup` or there is a way to accomplish this with 1 `through` model. Also I don't know if my 2 m2m in `Link` model are a proper way to accomplish the behavior that I want.

So I would like to know what is the way to organize these m2m models with an abstract model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is whether `DistributorPerson` and `DistributorGroup` really need to be separate tables. If they're very similar it might make sense to just use a single table. (For example, if you were modeling phone numbers you probably wouldn't use separate Home, Work, and Mobile tables, you'd instead use a single table with a type field.)

(And note that you can use [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) to allow different Django models to share the same database table.)

If you do need separate tables, then you might look at `GenericForeignKey`. This is a mechanism to allow foreign keys to reference objects from different model types. In your case this might look like:

```
class DistributorGroup(Distributor):
    distributor_links = GenericRelation(DistributorLink, related_query_name="distributor_groups")

class DistributorPerson(Distributor):
    distributor_links = GenericRelation(DistributorLink, related_query_name="distributor_persons")

class Link(models.Model):
    pass

class DistributorLink(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link);

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

See the documentation on [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) for examples and more detail.

Finally, if all else fails, you could indeed create two separate M2M tables for the two kinds of relation.

Note that none of this really has anything to do with abstract models. Abstract models are just a mechanism for code reuse in Django, they don't affect the tables or the queries you run on them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You've answered 1 of my question, so I am interested in the other one now. I can't have a single table for both distributors as their functionalities are rather different and so are the fields, but thank you for showing other ways of designing DB. The other question is about a `through` Model. If i stay with 2 m2m models do I need to create a `through` model for each of them (they will be absolutely the same)?

Comment: @pythad: Yes, but is there a reason you think you need two M2M tables? (I understand that you need two distributor tables.) Note that `DistributorLink` above *is* a custom M2M table, it just isn't declared as such on `Link` because Django doesn't offer that option with generic relations. Compare `a_link.distributor_persons.all()` (your old way) with `DistributorPerson.objects.filter(distributor_links=a_link)` (this way).

Comment: I've read a little about these generic relations, I thought a little bit different about them, now I understand what you are talking about. Using your code, is the way of implementing a `through` model the same as a normal one?

Comment: @pythad: I'm not sure I understand your question. `DistributorLink` *is* the through model, and you do it this way *instead* of declaring a `ManyToManyField` on `Link`. The effect is the same, though. Remember that `ManyToManyField` isn't a real field, it just creates some syntactic sugar for doing queries. Without it queries can be more verbose (see the example in my last comment), but other things will be easier than if you had two M2M tables (e.g. counting all the distributors associated with a link).

Comment: oh, okay, now I understand how this is going to work. I will try to implement this tomorrow. Thank you for you help, you've made many things clear to me!